# How does fan airflow relate to its RPM setting?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, airflow

A fan can run at 600 - 2000 RPM, at 2000 RPM it has 50 m<sup>3</sup>/h airflow.

0% = 0 RPM

100% = 2000 RPM

At 50% = 1000 RPM is the airflow halved to 25 m<sup>3</sup>/h?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does. Check this [link](https://www.axair-fans.co.uk/news/applications/understanding-basic-fan-laws/).

> The First Fan laws: Volume of Air
>
> The first law of fans is a useful tool when working out the volumetric
>   flow rate supplied by a fan under speed control or conversely working
>   out what the RPM would be to deliver a required volume of air and
>   hence what frequency to set a variable speed drive (VSD) to.
>
> Volumetric flow rate (V, m³/hr) varies directly proportional to the
>   ratio of the rotational speed (RPM) of the impeller.
>
> $V_2 = (\frac{U_2}{U_1})V_1$
>
> Where:
>
> : Volume 1, m³/hr – Original volume of air
>
> : Volume 2, m³/hr – New Volume of air
>
> : RPM 1 u/min – Original Speed
>
> : RPM 2, u/min – New Speed

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the energy requirement will be far from linear. I seem to remember a cube law in action.

Comment: Don’t fans, like propellors eventually stall?

Comment: @Transistor The link I gave tells about that too(The Third Fan Law: Power); and yup its a cube law.